# cross_val_score's n_jobs = -1 argument not working in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, cross-validation

i was trying to improve the accuracy and evaluate my Artificial Neural Network, but i encountered an issue that n_jobs = -1 of cross_val_score was not working,
i am using tensorflow on my cpu and my error was:-

> BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure
>   that the arguments of the function are all picklable.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

def build_classifier():
    classifier = Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(6,  kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu', input_dim=11))
    classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
    classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return classifier

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator= classifier, X= x_train, y= y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs= 1)
```